AssembleDebug failed
I have this problem:
Execution failed for task ':app:assembleDebug'.
com/android/build/OutputFile
I Don't have any problem with flutter doctor.
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.24.3, on Microsoft Windows [Versi¢n 10.0.19045.4894], locale es-AR)
[√] Windows Version (Installed version of Windows is version 10 or higher) [√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 34.0.0) [√] Chrome - develop for the web [√] Visual Studio - develop Windows apps (Visual Studio Community 2022 17.11.4) [√] Android Studio (version 2024.1) [√] VS Code (version 1.94.0) [√] Connected device (4 available) [√] Network resources
I Don't now what can I Do with this.!!!!!.
If anyone has any idea how to solve this problem. Thank you very much in advance

I guess you'r not post the error completely? Can you show your full error log?

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:assembleDebug'.


com/android/build/OutputFile


Try this:
flutter clean
flutter pub get
flutter run

I had this problem and I typed these commands in the terminal and it was fixed.
